# Getting Sankey diagram in D3 from csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I am attempting to create a **Sankey diagram** from a **csv** file.  I am utilizing code provided by *timelyportfolio*, and also the code from the d3 site (and even the sample csv files). However, when I try to run the code in Chrome, I am getting a blank Html page, indicating that the code is crashing. I attempted to redirect the source codes to files on my desktop, but I am still running into the same issues. (I am working on a computer with Windows XP)

I have pasted the code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SANKEY Experiment</title>
    <style>

    .node rect {
      cursor: move;
      fill-opacity: .9;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .node text {
      pointer-events: none;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-opacity: .2;
    }

    .link:hover {
      stroke-opacity: .5;
    }

    </style>
    <body>

    <p id="chart">

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Documents and Settings\jennifer.ducz\Desktop\sankey.js"></script>
    <script>

    var units = "Units";

    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
        width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 740 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),    // zero decimal places
        format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) + " " + units; },
        color = d3.scale.category20();

    // append the svg canvas to the page
    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Set the sankey diagram properties
    var sankey = d3.sankey()
        .nodeWidth(36)
        .nodePadding(10)
        .size([width, height]);

    var path = sankey.link();

    // load the data with d3.csv instead of d3.json
    //for another much simpler example uncomment the below
    d3.csv("C:\Documents and Settings\jennifer.ducz\Desktop\sankey.csv", function(error, data) {
    //d3.csv("d3noob_energy.csv", function(error, data) {
            //set up graph in same style as original example but empty
            graph = {"nodes" : [], "links" : []};

                    data.forEach(function (d) {
                        graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.source });
                        graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.target });

                        graph.links.push({ "source": d.source, "target": d.target, "value": +d.value });
                    });

                    //thanks Mike Bostock https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/pl297cFtIQk/Eso4q_eBu1IJ
                    //this handy little function returns only the distinct / unique nodes
                    graph.nodes = d3.keys(d3.nest()
                             .key(function (d) { return d.name; })
                             .map(graph.nodes));

                    //it appears d3 with force layout wants a numeric source and target
                    //so loop through each link replacing the text with its index from node
                    graph.links.forEach(function (d, i) {
                        graph.links[i].source = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].source);
                        graph.links[i].target = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].target);
                    });

                    //now loop through each nodes to make nodes an array of objects rather than an array of strings
                    graph.nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
                        graph.nodes[i] = { "name": d };
                    });

      sankey
          .nodes(graph.nodes)
          .links(graph.links)
          .layout(32);

    // add in the links
      var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
          .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", path)
          .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
          .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

    // add the link titles
      link.append("title")
            .text(function(d) {
            return d.source.name + " → " + 
                    d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

    // add in the nodes
      var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
          .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { 
              return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .call(d3.behavior.drag()
          .origin(function(d) { return d; })
          .on("dragstart", function() { 
              this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
          .on("drag", dragmove));

    // add the rectangles for the nodes
      node.append("rect")
          .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
          .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
          .style("fill", function(d) { 
              return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
          .style("stroke", function(d) { 
              return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
        .append("title")
          .text(function(d) { 
              return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

    // add in the title for the nodes
      node.append("text")
          .attr("x", -6)
          .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("transform", null)
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .filter(function(d) { return d.x < width / 2; })
          .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
          .attr("text-anchor", "start");

    // the function for moving the nodes
      function dragmove(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
            "translate(" + (
                   d.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(width - d.dx, d3.event.x))
                ) + "," + (
                       d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
                ) + ")");
        sankey.relayout();
        link.attr("d", path);
      }
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.

Edit:  This is the sample data I'm using courtesy of *timelyportfolio*

```
source  target  value
    Barry   Elvis   2
    Frodo   Elvis   2
    Frodo   Sarah   2
    Barry   Alice   2
    Elvis   Sarah   2
    Elvis   Alice   2
    Sarah   Alice   4
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Dear Lars,
I do not have any error messages.  Just a blank page.

Comment: Could you post a complete example somewhere please?

Comment: I pasted the code I'm using above.  In terms of the example, it's the same, but the sources have changed.

Comment: We won't be able to reproduce it without your data.

Comment: Ah.  My apologies.  I thought you meant the code.  I included the sample data I'm using courtesy of timelyportfolio in the original question:

Comment: The code and data you've posted work fine for me. Are you using the data exactly as you've posted it? That won't work because they're *tab* separated, not *comma* separated.

Comment: It was saved as a csv file, but even when including the data as such, it's giving me an error message for getting the d3 and sankey scripts.  It cannot seem to find the files.

Comment: If it can't load the D3 script, something is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not using MAMP or any other kind of virtual server, Chrome won't load the csv or any other local files other than the html. Try using a local webserver and everything should be fine

Comment: The local server issue was part of the problem.  I think the other issue was the computer I was working on would not load java scripts in general.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've never played with it; however, 
1) run your developer tools/console to see exactly which line is crashing the app

2) the following link discusses problems/solutions in formatting the data

http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/sankey-diagrams-description-of-d3js-code.html

Comment: Google console has been helping a lot!  Thanks for the advice! :)